# Using functors/applicatives on custom data types with multiple type classes?

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative, custom-data-type

Consider a Users type with two parameters, a and b. Clearly, this enables User to be composed of two different types:

```
data Users a b = User a b deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

How can we declare functors and applicative for this instance?

I've tried these approaches won't compile:

```
instance Functor Users where
   fmap f(User a b) = User (f a) (f b) 

instance Applicative Users where
   pure a b = User a b
   (<*>) User a b = (fmap a) (fmap b)
```

What's the reason these won't compile?

Comment: There is a kind mis-match, a Functor instance must have kind `* -> *` whereas your `User` type is of kind `* -> * -> *`. What you want is a [Profunctor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.2/docs/Data-Profunctor.html#t:Profunctor).

Comment: As well as the kind error, your `pure` implementation won't work because there's no variable `b` in the definition. How would you expect to be able to write the function `a -> User a b`?

Comment: @baxbaxwalanuksiwe Do you mean `Bifunctor`?

Comment: @ThreeFx yes, sorry.

Comment: @baxbaxwalanuksiwe Profunctor is *cofunctorial* in it's first argument. The arrow goes the other way around: `dimap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p b c -> p a d` as opposed to `bimap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d`.

Comment: @ThreeFx just noticed this, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [`Data.Bifunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) for a type class for ADTs which are functorial in both arguments. `User` is then just a fancy name for tuple, and this already supports such an instance. Deriving a bifunctor instance is possible in Haskell.

@Bakuriu suggests defining `User` as a `newtype` and the using the extension `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`.

For the second one, see [`Biapplicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-3.2.0.1/docs/Data-Biapplicative.html). As to be expected, its instance for `(,)` is:

```
instance Biapplicative (,) where
  pure = (,)
  ap (f, g) (a, b) = (f a, g b)
```

Comment: You can probably derive the pair's instance by using a `newtype` for `User` and use the extension `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`.